# Conversion of \n and other escapes for email piped to php

Tags: php, email, email-parsing

I'm trying to process emails piped to php. The resulting email (parsed into a variable) in php has a bunch of \n marks that do not seem to resolve back into new lines, etc., when php simply re-pipes it over with a `mail()`. Ideally, it should be readable when re-piped from the other end - is there a way to simply convert all these \n's \r's and other escape's?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) ? It converts \n and \r\n to `<br>`.

Comment: that will wok only in case of html-mail

Comment: i guess a roundabout solution might be to use `nl2br` then `str_replace` all the `<br>`'s with physical enter's ... but that's rather.. roundabout.. O.o